# Click INPUT button in web via excel vba not working

Tags: html, excel, vba

I am using the following code in order to click 'Select' button an a webpage. Onclick the button open the browser folder where you can select a file to upload on the webpage.
I am able to select the button, but nothing happens using btnInput.Click

```
Set ElementCol = appIE.Document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT") ' loop through all 'input' elements and find the one with the value "Submit"
For Each btnInput In ElementCol
If btnInput.Value = "Select" Then
btnInput.Select
btnInput.Click
Exit For
End If
     Next btnInput
```

and these are the attributes of the button

```
class ruButton ruBrowse
type  button
value Select
```

Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: You don't show the HTML or provide an URL. This is not [MCVE].

Answer (score 0):

Is hard to tell. I had a similar problem that the button required a mouse click no matter what. I think it depends on how they programmed the button. Other option that you can try is 'SendKeys'
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa202943(v=office.10).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa202943%28v=office.10%29.aspx)

this will mimic a mouse click.

Comment: might it be that this button is link (or it is) a silverlight application? Element_type: application/x-silverlight-2...